# Motodev won't lookup methods - can it be configured to do so?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am using [Motodev](http://developer.motorola.com/docstools/motodevstudio/javame/), an Eclipse-based development tool for Java ME / Motorola.  The problem is when you type a line of code that has a method, such as:

```
super.
```

It doesnt give options of what methods it has available?

How do I configure it to do this?

Or I'm guessing the instructions for eclipse would work the same.

Comment: Did you try pressing Ctrl-spacebar?

Comment: I just did, it says no default proposals

Comment: So it works, but you are calling it on something that has no options.  Try `this.` then Ctrl-spacebar instead.  You are using `super` incorrectly (`super()` is correct, `super.X()` is not).

Comment: Code context (as in a stripped down class) would also be useful.

Comment: I tried this. no luck still no completions available. i tried super().  same thing. its been doing this since i installed it and i reinstalled it and it still does the same thing

Comment: Are you in the Java perspective?  What happens if you press Ctrl-spacebar more than once in the same place?  What does it say at the bottom of the dialog?

Comment: at the bottom of the dialog it just says No completions available.

Comment: I had the same issue with MOTODev studio and was never able to solve it. I didn't have the same issue with Java in vanilla eclipse so I suspect MOTODev borks something up

Comment: yeah me too so screw motodev. Im going back to good ole fashion eclipse

Comment: Okay now ECLIPSE is doing the SAME THING!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@android_king22 MOTODEV Studio should work just like Eclipse does. Pressing '.' or ctrl-space should bring up the list of suggestions. What context are you typing 'super'? Are you able to build your project (i.e. is the SDK path correct)?

Is there a folder inside your SDK called "platforms/android-X/sources"? This is a common workaround to a particularly ugly problem in Eclipse where it takes 20-30 seconds for auto-complete to work. If you do have this folder but no actual source inside, it could be preventing the auto-complete mechanism from working.

Comment: Ive figured it out. It was java proposal wasnt enabled in the preferences

Answer (score 1):

You must enable "Java Proposals" and "Java Type Proposals" in Preferences|Java|Editor|Content assist|Advanced

Answer (score 0):

"super" calls a method in the superclass of whatever object you are currently using.  If no method is available (or your current class is not a subclass), then it won't show anything.  However, if there are methods available, it will automatically show (if you have Intellisense on).

Comment: Thats the thing.. It wont do that.. Even when i enter in Build. Or any method with a method selector.

Comment: You're sure the project's Build Path is set up properly and that your source file is under as Source Folder?  If it can't figure out what super refers to, it can't offer proposals on it.